# Shell script to insert string in line if it does not contain pattern

Tags: shell, string-matching

I have line which may or not contain [TICKET: 12345(any 5 digit number)] in it.
Want to write shell script, which will insert[TICKET: 54234(random 5 digit number)] if it does not exist.

Example:

```
Subject: [TICKET: 12345] test subject  // do nothing 
Output: Subject: [TICKET: 12345] test subject

Subject: test subject //insert [TICKET: 12345] 
Output: Subject: [TICKET: 12345] test subject
```

I tried some sed and awk commands but could not achieve the result

Comment: What would you like to do with the input line `Subject: [TICKET: 73]`?  Does the insertion only occur if the line matches `^Subject:`?  Your description of the problem suggests `sed -E '/^Subject: \[TICKET: [0-9]{5}\]/ ! s/^Subject: /Subject: [TICKET: '"$num"'] /'`, but I suspect this solution has many behaviors you will not like.

Comment: Thank you. I get the idea. If it does not find [TICKET: [0-9]{5}\] match, it should be completely removed and replaced. So  for [TICKET: 73] output must be - 
Subject: [TICKET: 12345] test subject not - Subject: [TICKET: 12345][TICKET: 73] test subject.

Comment: Please edit your question above to show the required output from that set of input. Also show your best attempt at coding a solution. Good luck.